# application-defined or object-defined error, bloody mystery

Tags: vba, excel-2010, userform

I'm a relatively uninformed programmer, apologies.

Below code for an Excel 2010 UserForm command button returns a application-defined or object-defined error.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim y, vfx, sapx, prx As String

y = Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).Range("B:B").Find(ComboBox2.Value).Row
vfx = Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).Range("1:1").Find("Vendor No").Column
sapx = Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).Range("1:1").Find("SAP Number").Column
prx = Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).Range("1:1").Find("Amey Price").Column

Lrow = Sheets("Macropage").Range("B:B")(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Userow = Lrow + 1

Sheets("Macropage").Range("A" & Userow) = ComboBox1.Value
Sheets("Macropage").Range("B" & Userow) = ComboBox2.Value
Sheets("Macropage").Range("C" & Userow) = Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).Cells(y, vfx).Value
Sheets("Macropage").Range("D" & Userow) = Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).Cells(y, sapx).Value
Sheets("Macropage").Range("E" & Userow) = Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).Cells(y, prx).Value

Sheets("Macropage").Range("A3:E" & Userow).Columns.AutoFit

Unload UserForm1

End Sub
```

The code causing the error appears to be: `Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).Cells(y, prx).Value` which I verified by sticking it in a MsgBox.

The only thing different about the column referenced by `prx` is it contains decimals rather than some text. I don't see why this should be a problem though.

Any info appreciated, even if it's just about the nature of a application-defined or object-defined error. From googling it only seems to mean Excel has a problem executing the script even if the compiler thinks it is fine.

Comment: Are you certain that `prx` has a value?  I would put a break point on that line, and see what its value is in the locals window.

Comment: And, if it doesn't have a value, my guess is that there is no column "Amey Price".

Comment: `Dim y, vfx, sapx, prx As String` - not related to your issue, but you realize only `prx` is actually declared as a `String` right? The others are implicitly declared as `Variant`.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a solution to question, but a rewrite of the code to better track the error.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    On Error GoTo ErrExit
    Dim y, vfx, sapx, prx As String

    Dim sheet, Macropage
    Set thisSheet = Sheets(ComboBox1.Value)
    Set Macropage = Sheets("Macropage")

    If thisSheet Then
        MsgBox "You have to select an input page", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Macropage Then
        MsgBox "You have to select a Macro page", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    y = thisSheet.Range("B:B").Find(ComboBox2.Value).Row
    vfx = thisSheet.Range("1:1").Find("Vendor No").Column
    sapx = thisSheet.Range("1:1").Find("SAP Number").Column
    prx = thisSheet.Range("1:1").Find("Amey Price").Column

    Lrow = Macropage.Range("B:B")(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Userow = Lrow + 1

    Macropage.Range("A" & Userow) = ComboBox1.Value
    Macropage.Range("B" & Userow) = ComboBox2.Value

    Debug.Print "y= " & y, "vfx= " & vfx, "sapx= " & sapx, "prx= " & prx

    Macropage.Range("C" & Userow) = thisSheet.Cells(y, vfx).Value
    Macropage.Range("D" & Userow) = thisSheet.Cells(y, sapx).Value
    Macropage.Range("E" & Userow) = thisSheet.Cells(y, prx).Value

    Macropage.Range("A3:E" & Userow).Columns.AutoFit

SafeExit:
    Unload UserForm1
    Exit Sub
ErrExit:
    MsgBox Error, vbCritical, "Error"
    Resume SafeExit

End Sub
```

Comment: please post the Debug.Print's string to get an idea of the error

Comment: Hello, I eliminated the error by removing `as string` from my declaration of the variables. `prx` could not be interpreted correctly by `cells()` as a string. (See Mat's Mug comment to my initial post).

Thanks for the response though, I'm likely to refer to this if I never need to hunt down an error cause.

Answer (score 1):

Oh god I'm an idiot. Mat's Mug pointed me to it, `prx` was a string - so `Cells()` couldn't interpret it correctly as a column index.

Not completely sure why I thought `var1, var2, var3 as type` would apply same type to all. I thought I had seen variables declared that way before..

Thanks all. It's OK to answer my own question, right?